# Given that Dave has a probability p to win each game, compute the expected number of runs after n games.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If “D” means Dave wins a game and “C” means Chris wins a game, then the sequence “DDCDDD” has three runs: “DD”, “C” and “DDD”.

I am unsure of where to begin :(

Comment: Start with the probability to get $1$ run.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the probability that D wins and $q=1-p$ be the probability that C wins.

Define and indicator variable $I_i$:

$$
I_i  = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{$i^{th}$  and $i+1^{th}$ wins are different}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Expected number of runs: $1+E\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}I_i =1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}EI_i$ where the $1$ comes from the fact that there is always $1$ run to begin with.

Now, $EI_i = P(I_i=1)$

$P(I_i=1) = \underbrace{p \times q}_\text{D wins, C wins} + \underbrace{q \times p}_{\text{C wins, D wins}}=2pq$

and hence expected number of runs: $R_n = 1+2(n-1)pq$

Check:

- $n=1$: $R_1=1$ (D or C win)
- $n=2$: $R_2=1+2pq$ (DD: $1p^2$, CC: $1q^2$, CD: $2pq$, DC: $2pq$, Total: $p^2+q^2+4pq = 1+2pq$)
- ...